# Fastest way to copy a table in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to copy a table in MySQL.  What is the fastest way?  Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE copy LIKE original;
INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM original;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE copy SELECT * FROM original;
ALTER TABLE copy ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

or is there another way?

EDIT: I'm worried about the indexes being re-created, how does mysql proceed executing these statements?

PS. can't use command-line tools like mysqldump, must be on-the-fly.

Answer (score 51):

This copies the structure of the table immediately, but not the data:

```
CREATE TABLE copy LIKE original;
```

This creates all the indexes the `original` table had.

It works this way in mysql `5.1.39`.

Comment: But, it will not copy triggers.

Comment: Note, this also will not copy foreign keys constraints.

Answer (score 50):

The fastest way using **MyISAM** tables while *preserving indexes*) and maybe other storage engines is:

```
CREATE TABLE copy LIKE original;
ALTER TABLE copy DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM original;
ALTER TABLE copy ENABLE KEYS;
```

You want to disable your keys for your database load and then recreate the keys at the end.

Similarly, for **InnoDB**:

```
SET unique_checks=0; SET foreign_key_checks=0; 
..insert sql code here..
SET unique_checks=1; SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

(As pointed out in the comments.)

Comment: Strange. INSERT with keys took 36 min, and this method took 10 + 26 min (insert + alter). 6 indexes, 28 M records, Win 7 x64, 8GB RAM.

Comment: An ENABLE KEYS cause a "repair table". Check your processlist in which way this happen. There are two kinds of:
1. repair table with keycache
2. repair table by sorting

The second one if the fastes way and will be only use if myisam_max_sort_file_size big enough.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table-speed.html

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table DISABLE/ENABLE KEYS` doesn't work in InnoDB, and gives below warning `Table storage engine for 'table' doesn't have this option`.

Comment: for innodb use ```SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;```
insert sql code here
```SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;```

Answer (score 14):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

"CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as possible. If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify these before the SELECT statement: "

```
CREATE TABLE bar (UNIQUE (n)) SELECT n FROM foo;
```

You can specify indices and data types (to avoid datatype conversion) in with both `CREATE TABLE LIKE` and `CREATE TABLE SELECT`. Which one is faster will depend on your setup.

Answer (score 12):

To copy with indexes and triggers do these 2 queries:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

To copy just structure and data use this one:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_new AS SELECT * FROM tbl_old;
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `INSERT INTO` instead of `INSERT`?

Answer (score 6):

Does `create table mynewtable (select * from myoldtable)` work in mysql? If so you can try it too.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to copy structure and all entries from one table to another table (by creating new table) is this query...

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table
   SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`SELECT INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into-statement.html), and use a [variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) as a go-between.

You'll have to create the receiving table, first, to have the same structure as the source table.

Best thing is, it's internal so it's fast. You'll lose your indexes, though.

Comment: Select into is not supported by mySQL

Comment: @Draco Ater - Yes, it does. It just uses variables.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Cause I think, that the variables will just hold the last value that was read by the select, but not all values in the table. As long as you don't use a cursor and don't want to copy tables with more than one row this solution does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using MyISAM you can also copying and renaming the induvidual files .
.MYD, .MYI, .FRM files in the backend

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Steps to take:

- Go to phpmyadmin
- Go to SQL

Execute this query

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `the_old_table`;
```

- Click options
  Check "Full texts" and press Go.

The result is a full CREATE TABLE statement. Edit the query until you are happy.

Resource: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE copy SELECT * FROM original;
```

Is a fast way but maybe not the quickest cause of indexes.

Comment: Please edit your answer and format it properly to make it readable.

Comment: This statement neither copy indexes nor triggers associated with this table.